# sentiment analysis and classification of the user based on this tweets?best approach for classifying the users(positive or negative) based on tweets?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, tweepy, text-classification

i am working on the classification(positive/negative) of the followers of a twitter account based on the followers tweets ,

**collecting data**

1. got all the followers and the their tweets from the respective account
2. sentiment analysis of each tweet and labelled as (positive/negative/neutral)

**which one of these are right approach?if no... is there any better approach?**

**my approach 1 for user classification:**

1. since polarity score of neutral is 0 ,delete all neutral labelled tweets
2. took the count of positive and negative tweets

   1. there are only 17% of negative tweets out of the all tweets(pos+neg)
3. i kept the threshold as 34% and grouped tweets based on the data user

   1. out the total tweets(pos+neg) by the user,if the negative tweets account more than 34% i am classifying him as the negative user otherwise positive user
4. Results:out of 300 followers i got 19 of them are negative rest of them are positive

**my code for approach 1**

```
users=set(classify_followers['users'])
user_to_classify=[]
classify=[]
for user in users:
    user_to_classify.append(user)
    temp=classify_followers[(classify_followers['users']==user)]
    if(temp.shape[0]>1):
        if(('positive' in set(temp['sentiment'])) 
           and ('negative' in set(temp['sentiment'])) ):
            positive_count=temp[(temp['sentiment']=='positive')]['sentiment'].count()
            negetive_count=temp[(temp['sentiment']=='negative')]['sentiment'].count()
            positive_percent=(positive_count/temp.shape[0])*100
            negetive_percent=(negetive_count/temp.shape[0])*100
            if(negetive_percent>=34):
                classify.append('negative')
            else:
                classify.append('positive')
        else:
            if('positive' in set(temp['sentiment'])):
                classify.append('positive')
            else:
                classify.append('negative')
    else:
        if('positive' in set(temp['sentiment'])):
            classify.append('positive')
        else:
            classify.append('negative')
```

**my approach 2 for user classification:**

1. since polarity score of neutral is 0 ,delete all neutral labelled tweets
2. clustering the tweets using k-means algorithm(from the prior knowledge it is known that there are more positive tweets,so the cluster with more tweets is a positive cluster)
3. grouped tweets based on the data user
4. predicted to which cluster each tweet of the user belong to and label the tweet with the cluster name
5. counted the cluster-labels ,and assign the user positive or negative
6. Results:out of 300 followers i got 19 of them are negative rest of them are positive

**my code for approach 2**

```
df=data[((data['sentiment']=='negative') | (data['sentiment']=='positive'))]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['tweets'])

true_k = 2
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++'
               , max_iter=10000, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)

print("Top terms per cluster:")
order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for i in range(true_k):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i),
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :20]:
        print(' %s' % terms[ind]),
    print

labels=model.labels_
print( np.bincount(labels))
d=pd.DataFrame()
d['labels']=labels
d['senti']=df['sentiment']
d['labels'].value_counts()
#to know which label having more data(more data is positive less is negative)
a=[i for i in range(0,len(labels)) if((d['senti'][i]=='positive') 
                                      and d['labels'][i]==1)]
b=[i for i in range(0,len(labels)) if((d['senti'][i]=='positive') 
                                      and d['labels'][i]==0)]
c=[i for i in range(0,len(labels)) if((d['senti'][i]=='negative') 
                                      and d['labels'][i]==1)]
d=[i for i in range(0,len(labels)) if((d['senti'][i]=='negative') 
                                      and d['labels'][i]==0)]
print(len(a),len(b),len(c),len(d))
users=set(df['users'])
prediction=[]
for user in users:
    temp=df[(df['users']==user)]
    temp=temp['tweets']
    Y = vectorizer.transform(temp)
    tweet_predictions=model.predict(Y)
    no_one=np.count_nonzero(tweet_predictions==1)
    no_zero=np.count_nonzero(tweet_predictions==0)
    if(no_one>no_zero):
        prediction.append('positive')
    else:
        prediction.append('negative')
```

is this the right approach for classifying the users based on the tweets?if no... is there any better approach?

Comment: What is the question? Do you have any problem with this?

Comment: Bravo for writing that code, but what's the
question?

Comment: @ Francesco Montesano @ Stuart Buckingham is this the right approach?if no... is there any better approach?

Comment: Is this the right approach **for what**?

Comment: @duskwuff     for classifying the users(positive or negative )based on the tweets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right approach is the third one:

Some judges evaluate a subset of your users and based on their tweets assign a sentiment-score to them. Then using some machine learning technique (I suggest SVM) you can train a model based on these labeled examples, providing as input their tweets' content, sentiment-score, absolute number of positives and negatives, percentage of negatives or other (aggregated) relevant features. Lastly you should apply the model to the unseen users to understand their polarity.

I don't want to introduce train-validation-test too, but this should be the way. Your approaches don't use machine learning to discriminate the users, since you are using it as a black box only to gather the tweets' polarity.